# Graphic appears blurry in Chrome and oversharpened in Firefox

Tags: css, html, adobe-xd, front-end-development

I exported the images on Adobe XD. For some reason the graphics on my page appear blurry in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge and oversharpened in Firefox. Also in Google Chrome when I go inside the inspector the images appear correctly, but when I leave it and refresh the page they appear blurry again.

When I open the graphics in Photoshop they show up correctly, not oversharpened or blurred.

Here is the page:
http://blulog.eu/iosapp/

[image: Blurred image in Google Chrome]
[image: Oversharpened image in Firefox]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. I checked your link in FF and Chrome, and they look identical.

Comment: Actually, in Firefox, I was able to replicate that pixelated look by zooming in or out by one step – can you check if that is the isssue?

Comment: @J.E - it must have something to do with the way the web page is constructed, because the [image itself](http://blulog.eu/iosapp/assets/img/iPhone_%D0%A5_Mockup@2x.png) does not do that when zooming in or out in Firefox. Of course in Chrome and Firefox, if you zoom in far enough then any raster image will get blurry. That's completely normal.